# How can I know which event caused the call to my IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Let's say I have a button.. how can I distinguish between single click and double click if they both call my IBAction? Is there a way to know which event caused the call, or to set up different actions, one for each type of event?

Comment: why can't you define two different IBActions if you need to tell which kind of event produced the call?

Comment: yes.. the point is how? When I CTRL-drag the element to the header file it just creates a generic action, it doesn't ask me for the event type. How can I do this?

Comment: @luca: Actions are generic by design. If single- and double-click should do different things, then they should send different action messages. For a button, double-clicking on it should do nothing different from clicking on it twice, which is why it doesn't have a separate double-click action; a custom view that should have a double-click action should have a separate property like [the one a table view has](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/setDoubleAction:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

In Cocoa, afaik, each control has a kind of "fixed" event it responds to. To manage double clicks, you should override the methods `mouseUp` or `mouseDown`, where you will get the information about the number of clicks.

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSInteger count = [event clickCount];
    <do_something_depending_on:count];
}
```

OLD ANSWER:

You can define multiple IBActions associated to the same control by displaying the actions tab for your control in Interface Builder and then connecting the proper event type to your controller action. Have a look at the attached image, hope it makes clearer. It displays the events available for button.

[image]

Comment: I can't see that on xcode though.. I'm working on Mac Application not iOS, there's no Sent Events at all..

Answer (score 2):

You can [ask the application for what event is currently being processed](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/currentEvent); for a mouse click, this will include the [click count](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/clickCount).

Note that even a button may fire its action for reasons other than mouse clicks, such as Full Keyboard Access (focus the button and press the space bar) or VoiceOver (put the VO cursor on the button and use the press action), so don't assume that your action was called in response to a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right , you should create two different IBActions for one click use UIControlEventsTouchUpInside and for two clicks UIControlEventsTouchDownRepeat (A repeated touch-down event in the control; for this event the value of the UITouch tapCount method is greater than one.)